# Symfony2 The CSRF token is invalid

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with Symfony. When I submit the `FOSUserBundle` register form on the built-in Symfony server (on the port `:8000`), it shows the error below:

> "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."

But, when I submit form on Apache server (by `/web/app_dev.php/`), all works fine.

Hidden token input exists in form.

Comment: your session could be invalid, did you tried after your cleared browser and server cache on the built-in server?

Comment: Is the `{{ form_row(form._token) }}` present in your form ?
Otherwise, it's more a permissions problem from the user used by the php built-in server.

Comment: @KhorneHoly thank you very much, it works now when I was cleared browser cache

Comment: @J.Ciszewski great that I could help you!. I wrote it down as an answer

Comment: @J.Ciszewski if this answer helped you, it would be good to accept it, so this question isn't stated as open anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your session could be invalid, after it timed out or due some changes in your code.

You need to clear the server and browser cache, then it should work again.